# Unique access path problems prevent updates to member SYSIXADV AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a problem with a job on the as400 consuming a lot of CPU over a long period.

I think it has something to do with a job that the system excecutes, the System index advisor to check or build indexes.

I have noticed that when we do data loads(From old DB to new DB) this process starts and takes long to end.

When I look in the joblog of the active job it gives the following:

[image]

Next page:

[image]

I can see there's a problem:

[image]

And it has to do with an index on the table `p6oispf` but I don't know what index or how to fix this problem...

What is causing this and how can we stop this from happening?

Comment: what version of IBM i?  Are you up to date on PTFs?

Comment: @Charles V6R1M0 , We are currenly looking into the PTF's...

Comment: @Charles Are the PTF's  accumulative? Had a look at : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011448

Comment: When they list PTFs like that doc does, you need all of them or the superseding ones.  It's possible some single superseding PTF replaces more than one of the individual PTF listed.

Comment: sysidxadv is arrival sequence.  There  should be no indexes on in.  Maybe one or two views, it should have one member.  Just clear it.

Comment: @danny117 Why is this happening? And how do I prevent this?

Comment: IDK I would check maybe a programmer put an index over sysixadv.   dspdbr sysixadv   make sure the objects are system created and not created by joe programmer

Comment: @danny117 I checked sysixadv only 2 views and both not created by programmer. They are system created. If the problem happens again I will check this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [following](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011448)
To recover from having a damaged SYSIXADV file, you should follow the below steps:

Note: Replace QSYS2 with QSYS2nnnnn if this is for an IASP.

Note: Replace zz with the CCSID used by character columns using the DSPFFD command on QSYS/QADBXREF file. Here's what to look for:

```
             Data        Field  Buffer    Buffer        Field    Column 
  Field      Type       Length  Length  Position        Usage    Heading
  DBXFIL     CHAR           10      10         1        Both     FILE   
                                                                 NAME   
    Field text  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :  File name              
    Coded Character Set Identifier  . . . . . :     37
```

- any CHAR column will do, and in this example the CCSID (Coded Character Set Identifier) is 37

These steps are best executed when application activity is quiesced.

1. ALCOBJ OBJ((QSYS2/SYSIXADV *FILE *EXCL)) CONFLICT(*RQSRLS)
2. DLTF QSYS2/SYSIXADVIX
3. DLTF QSYS2/CONDIDXA
4. DLTF QSYS2/SYSIXADV
5. CHGJOB CCSID(zz)
6. CALL QSYS/QSQSYSIBM
7. CALL QSYS/QSQIBMCHK

The linked doc provides a list of PTFs to check for along with an alternative recovery if the above doesn't work.

Comment: We did follow this example and could recover or restore the damaged SYSIXADV file... but i want to know what is causing this? and It seems to be happening more  every time there's losts of data being moved.

Comment: Probably an issue that has been PTF'd.   Also, how are you moving data?

Comment: We are moving it by using RPGIV functions. From the old DB structure to a new one we created.

Comment: Still don't know what caused this and how to prevent this but this answer has fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Command DSPDBR SYSIXADV shows that this file has two logical files over it, SYSIXADVIX and CONDIDXA.  The DSPFD SYSIXADVIX command shows that this file is uniquely keyed and lists the key fields in the Access Path Description section.